# WordPress Block Theme Navigation remove submenu on hover

Tags: wordpress, navigation, hover, rollover

I am working on a WordPress Block Theme (FCE) and want a vertical navigation on the left side.

When I add the Navigation Block vertical it is still opening the submenu while the mouse hover. The submenu shouldn't open when hover. I prefer it always open. How can I stop this menu hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to Classic Theme. As multiple things like this are not yet possible in full FCE Block Themes and they are still in Beta.